# Is it possible to call a postgres internal method from a util?

Tags: c, postgresql, makefile

Is it possible to make a function call (function is in Postgres code like hash_estimate_size(long, long) from a util like pg_ctl or pg_dump?

hash_estimate_size (long, long) is defined in file src/backend/utils/hash/dynahash.c and is declared in src/include/utils/hsearch.h.

I created a new util folder: src/bin/test_code with Makefile and test_code.c.

contents of Makefile

```
  PGFILEDESC = "test_code"
  PGAPPICON=win32

  subdir = src/bin/test_code
  top_builddir = ../../..
  include $(top_builddir)/src/Makefile.global

  OBJS= test_code.o $(WIN32RES)

  all: test_code

  test_code: $(OBJS) | submake-libpgport
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS_EX) $(LIBS) -o $@$(X)

  install: all installdirs
      $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) test_code$(X) '$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/test_code$(X)'

  installdirs:
      $(MKDIR_P) '$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)'

  uninstall:
      rm -f '$(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/test_code$(X)'

  clean distclean maintainer-clean:
      rm -f test_code$(X) $(OBJS)
```

test_code.c

```
  #include "postgres.h"

  #include "replication/walreceiver.h"


  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      printf("Has estimate value is = %zu\n", hash_estimate_size(10, 10));
      return 0;
  }
```

When I am running "make", it errors out like 
test_code.o: In function `main':
test_code.c:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to`hash_estimate_size'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test_code] Error 1

Any help in solving this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Most backend code cannot be called from utilities because it's not linked to utility programs. Nor can it easily be, since frontend code doesn't have `palloc` and memory contexts, `ereport`, and the other stuff backend code tends to rely heavily on.

Only code in `libpq`, `libpgcommon` and `libpgport` can be used from utilities. `src/backend` cannot, with a few exceptions that are recompiled as frontend code and linked into source trees (like `pg_xlogdump`'s use of the xlogdesc code).

If what you want to call is generic enough and will work when compiled as frontend code, consider submitting a patch to move it to `libpgcommon` (`src/common`).

Comment: Is it possible to find the value of the shared memory calculation ( the value calculated in the method CreateSharedMemoryAndSemaphores() in ipci.c file) without starting the postgres engine using some sort of utility or any other process?

Comment: That's core server code, so no. Why would you want to? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am doing some memory based analysis across all the Postgres versions with respect to different postgres.conf file configuration. I can get this value in the log file with a log level as "DEFUG3", butI just don't want to spin the db engine.

I'm looking for alternative ways to find this value.

Comment: Maybe modify the standalone backend to add a new flag to print it.

Comment: modifying the flag and printing is fine but that happens when I start the postgres db engine. I'm looking for a way to find out the value or call methods like SpinlockSemaSize(), BufferShmemSize() without starting the postgres db server.

Comment: Think about what `postgres --version` does. Do that.